# Why are the plyr interfaces with discarded results not compatible with %foreach%?

Tags: r, plyr, domc

I am writing a plyr based script to read input from files located in different directories, process that input, and then write the output to a different location.  Since I have a lot of input, it makes sense to use [doMC](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/index.html) with **d_ply**, but I was surprised to find some plyr functions do not accept the .parallel argument!

A quick look at the [plyr documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html) confirms that none of the functions which dispose of output (e.g **a_ply, l_ply, d_ply**) accept the .parallel argument:

```
d_ply       Split data frame, apply function, and discard results.  
Usage
d_ply(.data, .variables, .fun = NULL, ..., .progress = "none", .print = FALSE)
```

**My Question**: Does anyone know why this is the case?

Below is a concrete example.  My call to plyr looks like this

```
d_ply(input_df, c("ImageFiles","ShapeFiles", "FociFiles"), merge_files, .parallel=TRUE)
```

where *input_df* is a 3xN data frame containing input file names:

```
input_files[1:3,]
                 ImageFiles                     ShapeFiles
1         SQL_1_1_image.CSV         SQL_1_1_object.CSV.out
2 SQL_10002_10101_image.CSV SQL_10002_10101_object.CSV.out
3   SQL_1002_1101_image.CSV   SQL_1002_1101_object.CSV.out
                   FociFiles
1         SQL_1_1_object.CSV.out
2 SQL_10002_10101_object.CSV.out
3   SQL_1002_1101_object.CSV.out
```

The function **merge_files** is applied to each row of *input_df*.  It reads each file specified in the 3-tuple, processes the contents of each file, and merges those contents into one output data frame which is written to another directory.

However, when I tried a test:

```
d_ply(input_files, c("ImageFiles","ShapeFiles", "FociFiles"), merge_files, .parallel=TRUE)
```

I encountered this error:

```
Error in .fun(.data[[i]], ...) : unused argument(s) (.parallel = TRUE)
```

Thanks in advance for any enlightening answers!

Comment: I don't know _why_, but a hack to get around it would be to use `ddply` and simply return `data.frame()` at the end of `merge_files`. Or use it as an opportunity to return some more useful success/error code about the merging process.

Comment: @JohnColby Thanks, the suggestion to use the return value of ddply as an error code is a good one.

Comment: The `?_ply` family of functions now all accept a `.parallel` argument (except `r_ply`).

Answer (score 0):

Currently `_ply`-family functions accept `parallel` argument, please see below an excerpt from the documentation on `a_ply`:

> **Split array, apply function, and discard results**.
>
> **Description**
>
> For each slice of an array, apply function and discard results
>
> **Usage**
>
> a_ply(.data, .margins, .fun = NULL, ..., .expand = TRUE,   .progress =
>   "none", .inform = FALSE, .print = FALSE,   .parallel = FALSE, .paropts
>   = NULL) 
>   ...
>
> **Arguments**
>
> .parallel   if TRUE, apply function in parallel, using
>   parallel backend provided by foreach 
>   ...